# Unit Testing Controllers in Grails 1.3.7: redirectUrl is null or params isn't available

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-controller

I have the following code:

```
void testConfirmBookNotFound() {

    def book = new Book(id: 1, title: 'test book')
    mockDomain(Book, [book])
    mockDomain(BookProject, [new BookProject(id: 1, book: book)])

    def controller = new CancelController()
    controller.params.id = 5140
    controller.confirm()

    assertEquals "/admin/cancel/index", controller.response.redirectedUrl
}
```

If my test class extends `ControllerUnitTestCase` then `controller.response.redirectedUrl` is always `null`.  However, if my test class extends `GrailsUnitTestCase` (which I've read is the fix for the null url issue) then I get `No such property: params`.  What do I need to do to get this test to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `controller.redirectArgs.action` as in...

```
assertThat(controller.redirectArgs.action, equalTo("index"))
```

Comment: That worked after I changed my controller to use redirect action: "index" (note the quotes, so it doesn't return a closure)

Comment: Just a note for anyone using grails > 2, redirectArgs does not exist. See http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Problem-in-testing-my-controller-in-spock-td4495752.html